# Localhost on the internet

Tags: localhost, xampp

How can I set online my localhost? I am using XAMPP. How can I access to my localhost from another computer? I have tried using DynDNS, but I could not configure it properly, I think.

Comment: Have you forwarded the ports to the server?  At the most basic level `localhost` cannot be accessed from another computer.  If the server is not configured to be visible on an actual ip address it cannot be accessed from another computer even with the same network.

Comment: How can I set this on XAMPP please?

Comment: The configuration I talk about is on the hardware level.  Furthermore there are hundreds upon hundreds of guides on setting up XAMPP behind a router.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I set online my localhost?

You do not. The **local** is is **local** and local only.

> I am using XAMPP

I assume you wanted to ask "I have a webpage which I can access via localhost (`http://localhost/`, `http://127.0.0.1/`, or `http://::1`.)

In which case you need to bind you web server to not just localhost port 80, but also to your real IP. To do that you will need to edit its config file and restart the web server.

(It is the same for all other network programs. You run then and tell them where to listen. You do that by mentioning the IP and the port. Google on *bind address*)

If you use a weird setup such as NAT then you must either arrange for the right ports to be forwarded or get a proper IP. (Please add to the OP if you are at home with a real IP, at home behind a NAT or at a work place with a real IP).